# Filling empty list of lists with zeros to get a fixed size list of 5 tuples

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, list, numpy, nan

l have a sample of 1000 examples. Each sample contains  a list of 18 lists which are of  variable length and some of lists are empty.

Here is a sample :

```
len(My_list)
18
print(My_list)
array([list([(17, 163, 0.11258018, 15),(78, 193, 0.99713018, 17),(478, 94, 0.7299528, 2), (63, 268, 0.77531445, 3), (169, 279, 0.7947326, 4),(456, 140, 0.65013665, 7), (61, 301, 0.7433308, 8)]), 
list([]),
list([]), 
list([]), 
list([]), 
list([]),
list([]),
list([]), 
list([(63, 176, 0.18713018, 0),(199, 185, 0.88743243, 79), (282, 75, 0.752135, 84)]),
list([(62, 185, 0.13743243, 1)]), 
list([]),
list([(67, 156, 0.14346971, 2)]), 
list([(2, 15, 0.00639179, 3)]),
list([]),
list([]), 
list([]), 
list([]), 
list([])], 
dtype=object)
```

**What l would like to do ?**

for each list :

1-keeps the first 5 tuples

2- If a list is empty than create a list of five tuples as flollow

```
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]).
```

3- If a list is not empty but doesn't contain 5 elements then complete it to get five elements. As `My_list[12]` contains only one element `list([(67, 156, 0.14346971, 2)])` hence :

```
My_list[12]=list([(67, 156, 0.14346971, 2),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)])
```

The expected output :

```
array([list([(17, 163, 0.11258018, 15),(78, 193, 0.99713018, 17),(478, 94, 0.7299528, 2), (63, 268, 0.77531445, 3), (169, 279, 0.7947326, 4)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(63, 176, 0.18713018, 0),(199, 185, 0.88743243, 79), (282, 75, 0.752135, 84),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(62, 185, 0.13743243, 1),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(67, 156, 0.14346971, 2),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(2, 15, 0.00639179, 3),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]),
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)]), 
list([(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0)])], 
dtype=object)
```

**What l have tried ?**

```
My_list=np.asarray(My_list)

My_list = [joint if len(joint) != 0 else [(0, 0, 0,0)] for joint in My_list]
```

However, it doesn't make the job. It fills only empty lists with (0,0,0,0).Moreover, lists with one  or more elements skip them. And it is expected to fill all empty lists or lists with less than five elments with (0,0,0,0) to get five elements per list.

Any cue ?

Comment: You may want to add to each list a constant list with 5 zero elements and just take first five. It might be a bit memory-consuming, but does the job

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way: Glue 5 tuples to everything and trim later:

```
>>> ml
array([list([(17, 163, 0.11258018, 15), (78, 193, 0.99713018, 17), (478, 94, 0.7299528, 2), (63, 268, 0.77531445, 3), (169, 279, 0.7947326, 4), (456, 140, 0.65013665, 7), (61, 301, 0.7433308, 8)]),
       list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]),
       list([]),
       list([(63, 176, 0.18713018, 0), (199, 185, 0.88743243, 79), (282, 75, 0.752135, 84)]),
       list([(62, 185, 0.13743243, 1)]), list([]),
       list([(67, 156, 0.14346971, 2)]), list([(2, 15, 0.00639179, 3)]),
       list([]), list([]), list([]), list([]), list([])], dtype=object)
>>> 
>>> z = np.array([None, 5*[4*(0,)]])[[1]]
>>> z
array([list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)])],
      dtype=object)
>>> 
>>> res = np.frompyfunc(list.__getitem__, 2, 1)(ml + z, slice(5))
>>> res
array([list([(17, 163, 0.11258018, 15), (78, 193, 0.99713018, 17), (478, 94, 0.7299528, 2), (63, 268, 0.77531445, 3), (169, 279, 0.7947326, 4)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(63, 176, 0.18713018, 0), (199, 185, 0.88743243, 79), (282, 75, 0.752135, 84), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(62, 185, 0.13743243, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(67, 156, 0.14346971, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(2, 15, 0.00639179, 3), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)])],
      dtype=object)
```

Explanation: arrays of object dtype delegate operations like addition to their elements. Therefor `ml + z` combines each original list with a copy of 5x4 zeros.

Next we only need to cut every list back to 5 elements. The operation `somelist[:5]` can be written as `somelist.__getitem__(slice(5))` or even as `list.__getitem__(somelist, slice(5))`. This last form is what we "vectorize" using `np.frompyfunc`.

Comment: careful - your `z` replicates the tuples.  Though being tuples that may not matter.

Answer (score 1):

This a variant on @PaulP answer (and @Eir's comment).  It's close enough that I wouldn't post it, except it is faster (and possibly clearer).

Define a function that operates on one list at a time - using that idea of adding the pad, and stripping off unneeded elements:

```
In [209]: z = [4*(0,) for _ in range(5)]
In [210]: def foo(alist):
     ...:     return  (alist + z)[:5]
```

This can be applied to each list via list comprehension:

```
In [211]: [foo(row) for row in arr]
Out[211]: 
[[(17, 163, 0.11258018, 15),
  (78, 193, 0.99713018, 17),
  (478, 94, 0.7299528, 2),
  (63, 268, 0.77531445, 3),
  (169, 279, 0.7947326, 4)],
 [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)],
 ....
 [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]]
```

But if you want an object array, @Paul's approach using `frompyfunc` works nicely:

```
In [212]: np.frompyfunc(foo,1,1)(arr)
Out[212]: 
array([list([(17, 163, 0.11258018, 15), (78, 193, 0.99713018, 17), (478, 94, 0.7299528, 2), (63, 268, 0.77531445, 3), (169, 279, 0.7947326, 4)]),
       list([(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0)]),
  ....          dtype=object)
```

Timings:

```
In [176]: timeit np.frompyfunc(list.__getitem__, 2, 1)(arr + z, slice(5))
14.8 µs ± 18.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [184]: timeit [foo(row) for row in arr]
7.6 µs ± 26.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [213]: timeit np.frompyfunc(foo,1,1)(arr)
8.49 µs ± 27.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: Faster it is indeed.